# Connect legend of chart with selectInput

Tags: r, shiny, echarts4r

I am trying to build a shiny app that shows charts from the echarts4r package.

The app contains a select input, a bar chart and a scatter plot.

My goal is to connect these three objects. When I click on one of the items of the leged of the bar chart, I'd like the chart to be filtered by this element. At the same time the select input should reflect this selection.
The same should happen when items in the legend of the scatter plot are clicked.

Here is some example code:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(echarts4r)

ui <- fluidPage(

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("am", h3("Choose am"),
                        choices = c(0,1), 
                        selected = c(0,1),
                        multiple = TRUE) 
        ),

        mainPanel(
            echarts4rOutput("mt_plot"),
            echarts4rOutput("mt_scatter_plot")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    output$mt_plot <- renderEcharts4r({
        mtcars_1 <- mtcars %>%
            filter(am %in% input$am)  %>%
            group_by(cyl, am) %>%
            summarize(avg_mpg = mean(mpg))
        
        mtcars_1 %>%
            group_by(am) %>%
            e_charts(cyl) %>%
            e_bar(avg_mpg)
        })
    

    observe({
        input$mt_plot_legend_change
        input$mt_scatter_plot_legend_change
        
        if(!is.null(input$mt_plot_legend_change)){
            
            x <- input$mt_plot_legend_change}
        else{
            x <- input$mt_scatter_plot_legend_change
            } 
        

        updateSelectInput(session, "am",
                          selected = x
        )
    })
    
    output$mt_scatter_plot <- renderEcharts4r({
        mtcars_1 <- mtcars %>%
            filter(am %in% input$am)
        
        mtcars_1 %>% 
            group_by(am) %>%
            e_charts(disp) %>% 
            e_scatter(qsec, symbol_size = 15) 
    })
    
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The app above does not behave as I'd like. The following scenario shows what I mean.

1. Click on the legend of the bar chart on the value 1
   -> The behaviour is correct as the bar chart shows only the selected value and the select input changes its selected value to 1
2. Next: use the select input to bring back the value 0
   -> This works as well.
3. Next: Click again on the legend of the bar chart on the value 1.
   -> This time the bevior is different from the behavior in number 1. I'd like to have the same behavior as in number 1. The chart should be filterd by the selected value and the select input should reflect this as well.

Comment: I suppose in step 2, you wanted to say that you use the selectinput to bring back the value 0 since we selected onyl the value 1 in the legend, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you. I've just corrected that.